# Constructing Map in order of values inside List?

Tags: java

i have a list of customerIds like [12 , 10, 15, 18]. It can be any other numbers also and in any order.

I have List of objects(List customObjects ) where each object contains customerId at 0 postion 
and customer name at 1st postion.

```
customObjects[0]  ---> Object[0]  contains 10 as customer id and scott as customer name
customObjects[1]  ---> Object[0]  contains 12 as customer id and Mark as customer name
customObjects[2]  ---> Object[0]  contains 18 as customer id and Brian as customer name
customObjects[3]  ---> Object[0]  contains 15 as customer id and Pat as customer name
```

Now i want to construct a map where i get the value in the same order of list of customerIds

Expected result Map[12=>Mark, 10=>scott, 15=>Pat, 18=>Brian

**My Solution(but not optimized)**

I know i can achieve it with below simple algorithm but l am looking for the more optimized solution.(
Can we achieve it with comparator? Though i do not think so)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List <Integer> custIds= Arrays.asList(12 , 10, 15, 18);

    List <Object []> custObjects= new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object [] custObject1 ={10,"Scott"};
    Object [] custObject2 ={12,"Mark"};
    Object [] custObject3 ={18,"Brian"};
    Object [] custObject4 ={15,"Pat"};

    custObjects.add(custObject1);
    custObjects.add(custObject2);
    custObjects.add(custObject3);
    custObjects.add(custObject4);

    Map custMap= new LinkedHashMap();

    for(Integer custId : custIds){
        for(Object [] custObject:custObjects){
            if(custObject[0]==custId){
                custMap.put(custObject[0], custObject[1]);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("map is"+custMap);

}
```

i am looking for optimized solution(similar to my proposed solution or something different altogether) where i can save for loop iterations . Another solution can be, first i prepare the hashmap with key as custObject[0] and value as custObject[1]. Then run a loop on list on which i want ordering, get the value from hashmap and put it in linkedhashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st build a Map out of your customerObjects:

```
Map<Integer,Object []> byId = new HashMap<>(customerData.size()); //set size in advance
//O(n) hashing (assumming good hashing and no resizing)
for (Object [] customerData : custObjects) {
   byId.put(customerData[0],customerData);
}
```

and then you'll have faster lookup for you come to add them by id order:

```
for(Integer custId : custIds){
   Object [] custObject = byId.get(custId); //O(1) lookup
   custMap.put(custObject[0], custObject[1]);
}
```

overAll ~O(n) instead of your O(n^2)

Comment: can we achieve it with comparator?

Comment: @MSach - depends - do you need the customers ordered in the exact same order as the ids in custIds (which might be in any arbitrary order - not ordered), or do you want them ordered by id?

Comment: Yes i need the customers ordered in the exact same order as the ids in custIds

Comment: @MSach - so no, there'd be no point in using a Comparator. you _COULD_ write one which will compare based on id positions in the custIds list, but it'll be slower than my solution (because finding ids would be O(n) every time as the list isnt sorted)

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,ArrayList<String>> Map= new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

you use it for your requirement. I am using it in my application its working fine.

Comment: If you see my solution, LinkedHashMap is already there but i am looking for optimized solution where i can save for loop iteration

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is O(n*n). If you put custIds into map first, and then put custObjects into map , it will be O(n) (Assume LinkedHashMap find is about O(1))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> custIds = Arrays.asList(12, 10, 15, 18);

    List<Object[]> custObjects = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object[] custObject1 = {10, "Scott"};
    Object[] custObject2 = {12, "Mark"};
    Object[] custObject3 = {18, "Brian"};
    Object[] custObject4 = {15, "Pat"};

    custObjects.add(custObject1);
    custObjects.add(custObject2);
    custObjects.add(custObject3);
    custObjects.add(custObject4);

    Map custMap = new LinkedHashMap();

    for (Integer custId : custIds) {
      custMap.put(custId, null);
    }

    for (Object[] custObject : custObjects) {
      if (custMap.containsKey(custObject[0])) {
        custMap.put(custObject[0], custObject[1]);
      }
    }

    System.out.println("map is" + custMap);
  }
```